# Exclude maximum & minimum values records in oracle

Tags: oracle, max, minimum

I have following records in attendance table:

```
Attendance_Date    | Emp_Code
-------------------+-----------
07-FEB-14 08.55.00 | 1681
07-FEB-14 09.05.00 | 1829
07-FEB-14 17.31.00 | 1829
07-FEB-14 17.35.00 | 1681
08-FEB-14 08.54.00 | 1681
08-FEB-14 08.56.00 | 1829
08-FEB-14 17.31.00 | 1681
08-FEB-14 17.31.00 | 1829
08-FEB-14 17.31.00 | 1829
```

Now needs to exclude records with maximum time & minimum time stamp for every employee on date basis. Result should display only 1 record like:

```
Attendance_Date    | Emp_Code
-------------------+----------
08-FEB-14 17.31.00 | 1829
```

because emp_code 1829 has 3 records on 08-Feb-14.

Answer (score 1):

One option would be

```
SELECT attendance_date, emp_code
  FROM (SELECT attendance_date,
               emp_code,
               min(attendance_date) over 
                 (partition by emp_code, trunc(attendance_date)) min_attendance_date
               max(attendance_date) over
                 (partition by emp_code, trunc(attendance_date)) max_attendance_date
          FROM your_table)
 WHERE attendance_date != min_attendance_date
   AND attendance_date != max_attendance_date
```

This assumes that your data won't have ties or, if there are ties, that you'd want to exclude both of the tied rows if they have the minimum (or maximum) values.

Comment: I suppose one could also try using lag() and lead(), and detecting when either is null.

Comment: To break the ties, `dense_rank()` or `row_number()` could be used instead.